# Why we consider the relative velocity to take out time, in the river-boat problems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Its very simple, I have the statement that $$ t=\frac{d}{\overrightarrow{V_{BR}}Sin\theta} $$
Here $d$ Width of the river and $\overrightarrow{V_{BR}}Sin\theta$ is the $Y$-axis component of the velocity of the boat with respect to the river.
Since we are interested in the time taken by the boat to cover the width, we should consider the actual path of the boat, or the velocity of the boat with respect to the ground, which is conflicting with the above statement.
Please Explain how I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify whether the boat needs to arrive at A or at B. The boat needs to point slightly upstream in order to appear to travel straight across. So a component of its velocity will equal the velocity of the flow of the river. Note that in "real" rivers, the current is faster in the middle... but that is being neglected in this problem.

Comment: The boat needs to arrive at point A, but, due the addition of the river velocity vector, it is eventually arriving at point B, so, the time required to cross the river will be, $\frac{d}{V_{BR}Sin\theta}$ or $\frac{d}{V_Mcos\theta}$ , where $\theta$ is the angle between $V_{MR}$ and $V_M$.

Comment: Your drawing is deceptive- the boat need to point left of A in order to arrive there. And you need to define your angle in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference in either way :[image]

I assume that $V_{BR}$ is the velocity of the boat relative to the ground.
Let $O$ be the starting point of the boat. Then;
$$t=\dfrac{OB}{V_{BR}}=\dfrac{OB\sin{\theta}}{V_{BR}\sin{\theta}}$$

but $d=OB\sin{\theta}$ (by projection), then $t=\dfrac{d}{V_{BR}\sin{\theta}}$,

you can also say that $t=\dfrac{AB}{V_{BR}\cos{\theta}}$, i think they used $d$ in that problem because $OB$ is not given.

Answer (score 1):

If the boat wants to go straight across to A, it needs to point to a point LEFT of A (with the river flowing to the right). The following diagram illustrates this:

[image]

As you can see, the boat is using part of its velocity to counter the flow of the river, so it may cross in a straight line. The angle $\theta$ in my diagram is given by $\sin\theta = \frac{V_R}{V_B}$ where $V_R$ is the velocity of the river, and $V_B$ is the velocity of the boat relative to the water.

It is then easy to see that the velocity of the boat perpendicular to the river ($V_A$, the velocity that determines the time taken to cross) is $V_B\cos\theta$, and the rest follows.

Note - you did not define $\theta$ in your diagram; I am pretty sure that the angle I used is the complement of yours. So my $\sin\theta$ is probably your $\cos\theta$ and vice versa. But that shouldn't change the principle.

Comment: And in case if the required point to reach is B point, then.

Comment: You draw the appropriate vector diagram. The _net_ velocity vector needs to point to the destination. After that it's just geometry. If you can reach B just by pointing straight across the river and drifting with the current, that is the fastest route across (since all your propulsion aims to cross the river, and none to counter the current).